# Q: AudioKit: Total Newbie - Can't import AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

I'm following the HelloWorld intro video on the AudioKit website.  I've double-checked that I followed the instructions correctly.  I included the AudioKit.framework, but when I type import AudioKit into my code, Xcode cannot find the module.  I assume this is a search path issue, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.  As in the demo video, I have the AudioKit-iOS folder and my HelloWorld folder on my desktop.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers!

Comment: Flagged as being a general computing question as opposed to one about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Just in general for anyone who has these kind of problems, I'm willing to jump on screen share and just get your computer working for you. It's usually something very quick. Just email me directly via any one of my public address my name aure at audiokit.io or audiokitpro.com